# Retrieve all elements that match one query selector (JavaScript querySelector) instead of just the first

Tags: javascript

I have a web page that has many elements that match the querySelector given below;

```
document.querySelector('div[class="listing-headline"] > a > h3').innerText;
```

But when I run the above line, it only returns the FIRST matching element. Is there a way to return ALL matching elements?

Comment: `querySelectorAll()`

Comment: You will not be able to `.innerText` directly off of the resulting array like result though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Answer:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("[selector]");
```